# jQuery Circular Content Carousel "ca-content-item" width

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So I found this useful jQuery Content Carousel(http://tympanus.net/Development/CircularContentCarousel/), which I have been looking for for ages.

I have modified the codes to show from three boxes to five box:
http://helpmyedu.com/test/

However when I click "more", I have no idea where to modify the width of the div - ca-content-wrapper, to make it full width when "more" is clicked!

Thanks for the help!

Updated-------------------------------------
So far, I have managed to make displaying the extended 
items display properly, and closing the first three
items properly...

However, when I close the extended item, the last two on the right 
hand side doesn't show the original items (Please refer to the link
for what I'm talking about).

Also while the extended window is opened, there are spaces when I
try to navigate left or right....

Please help

Comment: can add your code in a jsfiddle

Comment: I tried, however with all the js and css, I don't know how to host my codes on jsfiddle...sorry

Answer (score 0):

In jquery.contentcarousel.js, use chrome developer or Firebug, After CTRL+F to find ca-content-wrapper.

When you find this, you have

```
openItem    : function( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache ) {
                cache.idxClicked    = $item.index();
                // the item's position (1, 2, or 3) on the viewport (the visible items) 
                cache.winpos        = aux.getWinPos( $item.position().left, cache );
                $wrapper.find('div.ca-item').not( $item ).hide();
                $item.find('div.ca-content-wrapper').css( 'left', cache.itemW + 'px' ).stop().animate({
                    width   : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px',
                    left    : cache.itemW + 'px'
                }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing)
                .end()
                .stop()
                .animate({
                    left    : '0px'
                }, opts.itemSpeed, opts.itemEasing, function() {
                    cache.isAnimating   = false;
                    cache.expanded      = true;

                    aux.openItems( $wrapper, $item, opts, cache );
                });

            },
```

You can see :

```
   width    : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px',
```

Try to modify this value on this js file.

Comment: Yes, I've managed to find this line, but I have no idea how it works...

What's cache.itemW?

Comment: cache.itemW represents the width of an element .ca-item so 220. If you want to have right width, find the coefficient for multiply this value. You have width   : cache.itemW * 2 + 'px', and the coefficient is 2, change this value to have the good ratio. And it is the same to manage the left of each ca-item

Answer (score 0):

also, you've got to change this code:

```
switch( val ) {
case 0          : return 1; break;
case cache.itemW        : return 2; break;
case cache.itemW * 2    : return 3; break;


}
```

and add one line for each item you want to display in the content wrapper, in this case I want to display 4 items you go like this:

```
switch( val ) {
case 0          : return 1; break;
case cache.itemW        : return 2; break;
case cache.itemW * 2    : return 3; break;
case cache.itemW * 3    : return 4; break;

}
```